# Should I internally rotate legs pulling the deadlift up?

Tags: deadlifts

Normally before deadlifting, we externally rotate the legs outwards, I want to ask, when do the pull, are we supposed to intentionally rotate inwards? THanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No, that would be counterproductive if you can even manage to do it.

External rotation at the hip shortens the hip extensors, while internal rotation lengthens them. Intentionally internally rotating your hips on a deadlift would be counterproductive, since it would lengthen some of the muscles you are trying to contract. Having just tried this, I’m having trouble even doing what you are describing. Doing a light pause deadlift, then intentionally internally rotating causes me to just lose all tension and drop the bar.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. I also had a similar result of trying this, just wanted a second confirmation.